# WCF Service Migrated to IIS 10 - Consistent 503

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, windows-10, iis-10

A computer hosting a WCF service at my work was swapped out from a Windows 7 instance running IIS 7 to a Windows 10 instance running IIS 10.

The WCF service is a third party service that allows remote control of the robotic system the computer is connected to, so I have no access to the source code.

I've tried using MS Deploy to migrate, I've tried perfectly replicating every single setting in IIS and installing all the necessary .Net Framework versions, and I've completely re installed .Net Framework twice.

No matter what I do it always results in a 503 - Service Unavailable. The logs in HTTPERR simply state "N/A" for each failed request to the svc file.

Yes, I've added the svc Mime type and handler.

Also Server Manager has been no help, as it's Windows 10 and not actually a server.

EDIT:
Here are the settings I've copied over:

Application pool for default site uses .Net CLR 4.0, with Application Identity and 32-bit applications disabled.

Application pool for the WCF service uses .Net CLR 4.0, with Network Application as its identity and with 32-bit applications enabled.

It works perfectly fine on the old server, so I'm still at a loss as to why it doesn't work on the new one.

Comment: Create a brand new WCF app and deploy to the same server and see what you get for that app.

Comment: @LexLi still 503. The application pool I'm using for it is .Net CLR 4.0 with Application Identity and disallows 32-bit applications.

Comment: Can you run cmd "http show urlacl" on the machine? Might be useful to check if the port you are using is not reserved by something else installed on the machine. I know this was a pain point for me before when getting a new server.

Comment: @TravisActon urlacl properly reserved for the location, this was taken care of in the initial creation of the inetpub folders by a third party application

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Travis Acton for the suggestion to check netsh http show urlacl!

I decided to run the delete command for the port despite it not being shown, and it indicated that the port reservation was successfully deleted. For some reason it was unlisted by netsh.

So now it's all working fine! Thanks so much for the help!